# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error The SQL being executed in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Reference from [Specified Twice Table for 'DELETE' in MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998410/specified-twice-table-for-delete-in-mariadb)

After I implemented the query from that reference into the code, I made an error in yii2

Query :

```
public function actionDeleteduplicate($date){
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand("DELETE t1
                                    FROM HrAttLogsFormatted t1
                                    INNER JOIN
                                    (
                                        SELECT FingerId, MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinCreatedDate
                                        FROM HrAttLogsFormatted 
                                        WHERE DateIn = '".$date."' AND Late != ''
                                        GROUP BY FingerId
                                        HAVING COUNT(FingerId) > 1
                                    ) t2
                                        ON t1.FingerId = t2.FingerId AND t1.CreatedDate = t2.MinCreatedDate
        ")->queryAll();

        $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

Result :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error The SQL being executed was:  DELETE t1
>   FROM HrAttLogsFormatted t1 INNER JOIN (  SELECT FingerId,
>   MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinCreatedDate  FROM HrAttLogsFormatted WHERE
>   DateIn = '2019-05-03' AND Late != ''  GROUP BY FingerId HAVING
>   COUNT(FingerId) > 1 ) t2  ON t1.FingerId = t2.FingerId AND
>   t1.CreatedDate = t2.MinCreatedDate

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

Comment: You should probably use `execute()` instead of `queryAll()` for delete queries.

Comment: @rob006 Thank you, I forgot that there has a `DELETE` function not only `SELECT` where the function is executed by `execute()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be related to the fact you have the same table in delete and in subquery. Try force the db engine to use a temp table using a nested query:

```
DELETE t1
FROM HrAttLogsFormatted t1
INNER JOIN ( 
  select FingerId, MinCreatedDate
  FROM   (
    SELECT FingerId, MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinCreatedDate
    FROM HrAttLogsFormatted 
    WHERE DateIn = '".$date."' AND Late != ''
    GROUP BY FingerId
    HAVING COUNT(FingerId) > 1
  ) t3 
) t2  ON t1.FingerId = t2.FingerId AND t1.CreatedDate = t2.MinCreatedDate
```

BTW: You should not use a PHP var in SQL directly, you should take a look at [binding params](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao#binding-parameters).